# How to print specific product information provided by a CMS

Tags: magento-1.8, product-attribute, cms, print

I understand that magento has a print.css file that by default allows users to view/print their past orders. However, I would like users to have the option to print specific product information from a product page that works along the same lines.

Is there an easy way to do this? The product data in question is provided by a CMS, so Somehow I need to print a "section" of any product page, whose contents will contain the same fields but different values depending on the product.

Thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2618980/158325 perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to add the information into your product detail page. then you hide it with normal CSS and show it on printing. `print.css` is to rearrange the site when printing, remove the menu, etc. everything which isn't needed on a print.

What is your exact problem?

Comment: someone help me : https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/195376/57334