# How To Give Product Details Print By Admin > Catalog - > Managed Products

Tags: magento-1.9, products, print, multiselect

From admin managed products, what are all the products i selected (Using checkbox) i need those products get a printout, printout like products image, name, description?

Is Possible?

[image]

Comment: Yes it is possible. But it is too broad to answer. You really need to write a full module for this to achieve.

Comment: I am a newbie, could you please help me.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy : Atleast can I get resource place...

Comment: I don't know any resource that does this functionality, really sorry.

Comment: Did you create the paid module?

Comment: I don't have any paid module for this. If I get time to do this, I will put it as an answer. Magento uses `Zend_Pdf` to generate pdf, which makes the work even harder!!!